# Some INPUT tags are not working

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, checkbox

I have a `form` [HERE](http://www.erase.com.mx/erase/solicitar-servicio.html)

At a first sight everything works great but when I resize the the browser to a middle-small size some `input` tags (but not all of them) stop working (like the 3 `input` tags after says "Información del Evento"). Also the first `checkbox` group does not work anymore, but the second group works well.

The weird thing is that when the browser has a large size every tag seems to work perfect. I'm using the Twitter-Bootstrap so I don't know if its something related to this.

I have also validated the code with the W3-Validator and got just some few warnings.

Hope anyone have an idea abut what is going on here.

```
<fieldset class="pb-md">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="featurette-heading centerText mb-md">Informaci&oacute;n del Evento</h3>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="tipoEvento">Tipo de Evento</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tipoEvento" id="tipoEvento" placeholder="tipo de evento">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="lugarEvento">Lugar</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lugarEvento" id="lugarEvento" placeholder="lugar del evento">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="fechaEvento">Fecha</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="fechaEvento" id="fechaEvento" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="numeroInvitados"># de Invitados</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numeroInvitados" id="numeroInvitados" placeholder="lugar del evento">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="porcentajeForaneos">% de Foraneos</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="porcentajeForaneos" id="porcentajeForaneos" placeholder="% foraneos">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 mt-xs mb-sm"><hr class="featurette-divider"></div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="tipoEvento">Tipo de Ceremonia</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tipoCeremonia" id="tipoCeremonia" placeholder="tipo de ceremonia">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="numeroInvitadosCeremonia"># de Invitados</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numeroInvitadosCeremonia" id="numeroInvitadosCeremonia" placeholder="... de ceremonia">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="numeroHorasCeremonia"># de Horas</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numeroHorasCeremonia" id="numeroHorasCeremonia" placeholder="# de horas">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="desdeCeremonia">Desde las...</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="time" name="desdeCeremonia" id="desdeCeremonia" placeholder="00:00 am">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="hastaCeremonia">Hasta las...</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="time" name="hastaCeremonia" id="hastaCeremonia" placeholder="00:00 pm">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 mt-xs mb-sm"><hr class="featurette-divider"></div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="tipoRecepcion">Tipo de Recepci&oacute;n</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tipoRecepcion" id="tipoRecepcion" placeholder="tipo de recepci&oacute;n">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="numeroInvitadosRecepcion"># de Invitados</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numeroInvitadosRecepcion" id="numeroInvitadosRecepcion" placeholder="... de recepci&oacute;n">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="numeroHorasRecepcion"># de Horas</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="numeroHorasRecepcion" id="numeroHorasRecepcion" placeholder="# de horas">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="desdeRecepcion">Desde las...</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="time" name="desdeRecepcion" id="desdeRecepcion" placeholder="00:00 am">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="hastaRecepcion">Hasta las...</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="time" name="hastaRecepcion" id="hastaRecepcion" placeholder="00:00 pm">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 mt-xs mb-sm"><hr class="featurette-divider"></div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <label for="diasEvento">D&iacute;as del Evento</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="diasEvento" id="diasEvento" placeholder="#">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="pedida">Pedida</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="pedida" id="pedida" placeholder="#">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="despedida">Despedida</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="despedida" id="despedida" placeholder="#">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="ensayo">Ensayo</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="ensayo" id="ensayo" placeholder="#">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <label for="tornaboda">Tornaboda</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="tornaboda" id="tornaboda" placeholder="#">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12 mt-xs mb-sm"><hr class="featurette-divider"></div>

                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <label for="hotelesSede">Hoteles Sede</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hotelesSede" id="hotelesSede" placeholder="hoteles sede">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                            <label for="plan">Plan</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="plan" id="plan" placeholder="plan">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 mt-md mb-xs"><hr class="featurette-divider"></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out exactly *why* this is happening, but I *can* provide a fix.

The problem is that all of your `<input/>`s are contained within `<div>`s. The `<div>`s have a `position:relative` style, but the `<input/>`s do not. When the page is resized, the `<div>` are going on top of the `<input>`s; when you click on an `<input/>`, you are actually clicking on the `<div>` above it.

If you add the following attributes to the CSS for `.form-control`, then the inputs will work when the page is resized:

```
.form-control {
    ...
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999; /* giving this a high number is the equivalent of using "Send to Front" in PhotoShop */
}
```

Comment: Great! Now the `<input type="text, date, time, number">` are working well but the `input type="checkbox"` are still not working, could it be because of the same reason?
Is there an other fix for them? Thanks Cris

Comment: This can be fixed the same way: find a way to target those elements in CSS (maybe with `input { ... }`), and then add the `position` and `z-index` attributes from the answer.